# How to change the new attribute to the top of near by short description

Tags: product-attribute, magento1.9.3

I just create a new attribute on magento 1.9.2, but i have one problem...
How can i put this attribute "Product status**" on the top  near by short description?

as u can see it in[image: attribute status] the picture

Answer (score 0):

Open your root directory

app/design/frontend/[Theme package]/default/template/catalog/product/**view.phtml**

find the **$_product->getShortDescription()**

add code after short description for show the attribute value:

```
<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getProductStatus(), 'product_status') ?>
```

after adding the code it will show.

Comment: i just tried, but no luck...